# How to dynamically create option definitions in a views style plugin?

Tags: views, forms

When creating my own Views 3 Style Plugin in Drupal 7, how can I create an option for each field that is loaded into the view?

I have tried looping through the views field handler (that works in the options_form function) but it seems I'm forced to hard code option definitions in the option_definition function.

```
//Get out Field Handler
$handlers = $this->get_view_field_handler();

//Set Some Options we - for some reason - can't set in the option definition
//because the "handler" object cannot be identified.
foreach($handlers as $i => $handler){

   $this->options[$handler->field . '-color'] = array('default' => "#666");

}
```

Is there some other way I can access the fields used in a view and dynamically create an option for each?